# how to find place values for integers

Tags: java, max, min

I have 4 variables that hold values as `int` `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and`x4`. How do I sort them in descending order? (Code is shown below)

```
public void calculateButton() {

    totalVoterInteger = Integer.parseInt(totalVoters.getText());
    y1 = Integer.parseInt(projectOneVoters.getText());
    x1 = totalVoterInteger*y1;

    y2 = Integer.parseInt(projectTwoVoters.getText());
    x2 = totalVoterInteger*y2;

    y3 = Integer.parseInt(projectThreeVoters.getText());
    x3 = totalVoterInteger*y3;

    y4 = Integer.parseInt(projectFourVoters.getText());
    x4 = totalVoterInteger*y4;

    System.out.println(x1);
    System.out.println(x2);
    System.out.println(x3);
    System.out.println(x4);
```

Comment: Even if your implementation really only needs 4, it is way cleaner to store the values in a collection and then sort them

Comment: Have you tried putting them in a list and using Collections.sort() method

Comment: Do you want the highest value or to know what fields hold the highest value ? The last one require a comparable POJO !

Comment: @sshashank124 I would say not a duplicate, but can be interesting to user7385522 to check this !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort` function:

```
int[] arr = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```